# Python transform string into dataframe using tab as separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a utf-8 string which I want to transform into a data frame. My code to do so is using the read_fwf from pandas. I passed the delimiter '/t' as well.

```
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(messFile), delimiter='\t', skiprows=[0,1], widths=None)
```

My initial string is separated by tabulators and those are not realized in the final df:

```
1      0,4\t123,7\t3\t0,34342\t1,3\t25,1\t1,4\t254,1\... 
2      0,5\t123,7\t3\t0,12123\t11,0\t25,1\t1,1\t254,1\... 
3      0,6\t123,7\t3\t0,11123\t11,0\t25,1\t1,1\t254,1\...
```

I have no idea why the tabs are not written into separated columns.

Comment: What  about  `df = pd.read_csv(messFile, sep='\t', skiprows=[0,1])` ?

Comment: This leads to '--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit'. Since I'm not running it local it's seemed to me impossible to change the config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is tab separated.  `read_fwf()` is for "fixed width" data meaning there are no delimiters.  You want to use `read_table()` instead.

For the fact that `read_fwf()`'s documentation is confusing by suggesting that you can use `delimiter` when you actually should not, I have submitted a bug report: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17056

Comment: Tank you! The documentation confusing.